# Cannot create list of Cartopy U.S. State shapes

Tags: python-3.x, cartopy

So I'm trying to loop thorugh the list of U.S. states provided by Cartopy using their shapereader and the natural earth dataset. When I go to make a list though, I find an encoding error:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 5: invalid start byte

I'm hoping that you fine folk can help me.

Here's a minimal example.

```
import cartopy.io.shapereader as creader

state_shapes = creader.natural_earth(resolution="10m", category="cultural",
    name="admin_1_states_provinces_lakes_shp")
    
state_shapes = list(creader.Reader(state_shapes).records())
```

I am absolutely mystified as I used this plenty of times in the past.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. cartopy v0.18.0.

Comment: I also have Cartopy 0.18, which suggests that I have a local problem going on. Thanks for checking! I'll talk with the sysadmin to see if they might have an idea.